# Copy failed in batch script

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I have the following lines in my VS's bat file:

```
copy "%1web.%2.config" "%1web.config" /y
copy "C:\inetpub\Config\%2\api\smtpSettings.config" "%1smtpSettings.config" /y
```

Idea is to copy environment-related configuration into project's main configuration files. `%1` is a path to project, `%2` is a environment name.

The file is executed via VS's pre-build step: `"$(ProjectDir)Deploy.bat" $(ProjectDir) $(ConfigurationName)`

Problem is that first line works fine, while second all the time fails with:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked the path, it is valid, at least pasting it into windows explorer I can navigate to file. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "an environment name"?

Comment: @Magoo Development or Production for example

Comment: And how are you setting this variable?

Comment: Can it be that such error is raised because of security ? Like inetpub is kinda restricted folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that `"C:\inetpub\Config\Development\api\smtpSettings.config"` or `"C:\inetpub\Config\Production\api\smtpSettings.config"` does not exist.

If they do exist, then you may be facing a security error.

Comment: They do exist. Any ideas how can I handle security issues via batch script? Or just adjust settings in folder's options?

Comment: I know , and want to know nothing about windows security other than how to kill it off completely for my own machines.